# Событие нажатия сочетания клавиш

Tags: c#

Интересует, как можно реализовать событие, которое будет срабатывать, при нажатии определенного сочетания клавиш, причем ВНЕ активного самого приложения.

То есть, запускаем нашу программу, включаем еще одну, совершенно другую программу, и нажимая сочетание клавиш CTRL+K (к примеру), у нас срабатывает событие в первой программе.

[ps. Глобальный прехват нажатия клавиш]

Answer (score 2):

- [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)
- [Перехват клавиатуры Windows на C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dmandreev/windows-c)